# Redirecting from one intent to another in dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am trying to transition between intents. I have `welcome` intent and based on user response, I want to either redirect to `Search` intent or to `CheckInternet` intent.

I have given output context as `search` and `interconnection` in `Welcome` intent and then given them as input context in relevant intents. But still not able to chain them together.
Unfortunately, I don't have knowledge of Dialogflow yet, as using this for hackathon first time to check its capabilities. Any help would be great

Comment: You may want to update your question to include screen shots of the Intents in question and anything illustrating how they are not "chaining together".

Answer (score 1):

Intents in Dialogflow aren't nodes in a state machine. You don't "transition" between them. Intents reflect *what the user says or does*.

So, to give your example:

- When they start the agent, the `welcome` Intent is triggered based on the welcome event.
- If, at any point, they say "search", then the training phrases in the `Search` Intent might match, so the webhook or responses for it would be triggered.
- Or, if they said "check", then the training phrases in the `CheckIntent` Intent might match, so the webhook or responses for it would be triggered instead.

If you need to limit under what circumstances these phrases would be accepted by an Intent, you can add a Context and make sure that Context is valid. But you usually only want to add that once you get it responding in the more general case.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to add both `Search` and `CheckInternet` as "Follow-up Intents". To do so, create two new Intents and assign the contexts `search` and `interconnection` to them respectively as Input Context.

When the user says something that should lead to `Search`, set `search` as output context and for the next utterance `Search` Intent will be considered (if sample utterance match).

I hope that's clear enough, I'm happy to explain that in detail, too. This way I configured a nicely working Chatbot with 20+ Intents once :)